# unable to start mysql - start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie and trying to learn Ubuntu and MySQL together. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04. I also installed MySQL using the following commands:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
apt-get install mysql-client
apt-get install mysql-common
```

Then I tried to start MySQL using the following command:
`sudo start mysql`

I get the following message:
`start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused`

I get the same message when I tried to start it as a root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for starting `mysql` run the following command and enter password:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

`root` can be replaced by any other username, of course, you can view `mysql` service status with this command and start or restart it if necessary:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

Comment: don't forget to mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about such commands, but usually after installing a package, it is needed to register service, like

```
sudo systemctl enable mysql
```

and then start it

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

check if it has been started ok

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```

If something went wrong, you'll see the last error.

Comment: @NerdOfCode That's a first *answer*.  It's not a question...  Don't assume that because a user has Rep 1 they're automatically asking questions...  This OP is one of the good ones!  **;-)**